# Android Camerax two cameras previews simultaneously

Tags: android, camera

I have attendance device with 7.1.2 Android. It has two cameras, normal and IR.
I need to show preview from both cameras in same time, but it opens just preview from first camera.
Getting this is logs:  Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)

But device come with some "demo app" and there is preview from both cameras in same time. So device can handle this.
My question is, can I achieve same result with camerax libraries, or is there anything similar?
Thank you

Comment: These bespoke devices may have weird compatibility problems. To begin with, can you actually start either camera from your CameraX app?

Comment: Yes, I am able to open both cameras with camerax

Answer (score 1):

CameraX is relatively new and focuses on "ease-of-use".  It makes setting up camera sessions relatively easy, but reduces the flexibility offered to clients.

Your best bet is to use Camera2 API and open the specific CameraDevices directly.  This is probably what the demo app is using.
https://developer.android.com/training/camera2

Comment: … or maybe the device is still using LEGACY camera. At any rate, the list of devices that officially support cameraX is [rather short](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/devices).

Comment: See this [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151866349). It was resolved as *Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)* with comment that cameraX only supports dual camera for Android P (API 29+) on Pixel 3 & 4.